# Implementation of the DefaultContractResolver results in a 404

Tags: .net, json, json.net

In our app, we use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize and serialize video feeds object. We had Newtonsoft.Json 3.5 before. and things were running OK. But recently, we upgraded Newtonsoft.Json.dll to 4.5 because TweetSharp 2.3 depends on it. And this has resulted in our video feeds page returning 404. I narrowed down the problem, seems like this code is causing the problem

```
JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    collection, 
                    Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new GetClipContractResolver(IncludeMedia) });

class GetClipContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private bool IncludeMedia { get; set; }

        public GetClipContractResolver(bool includeMedia)
        {
            this.IncludeMedia = includeMedia;
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(JsonObjectContract contract, System.Reflection.MemberInfo member)
        {

            // remove Clip.Media
            if (member.DeclaringType == typeof(KenticoWhiteLabelCore.Core.VideoDataServiceConsumer.VideoDataClip))
            {
                if (member.Name == "Media" && IncludeMedia == false)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return base.CreateProperty(contract, member);
        }
    }
```

JsonConvert.SerializeObject works OK, but the JsonProperty CreateProperty() override method is causing the problem. I removed it, and everything works fine. Any ideas why? we cannot do without overriding CreateProperty(). Suggestions on how to fix it? Why it would stop working all of sudden in Newtonsoft.Json 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Version 4.5 has different method signatures.